# Getting Node Errors Running composer-rest-server

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've been following the latest (i.e. for Hyperledger Composer v0.19) tutorial.  Everything worked but now, after a shutdown and restart of Fabric (which is v1.1) when I try to run the composer-rest-server to create the rest server for my network I get errors of the form:

Expected directory: node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v48-darwin-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system

Running 'npm build' as suggested makes no difference.  Anyone know why composer-rest-server should suddenly be looking for new versions when I didn't change or upgrade anything?

Fabric is up and running and responds to a 'composer network ping' command.

I'm running node v8.9.1

Comment: Should have added that the initial error when issuing the composer-rest-server command is: 'Connection fails: Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection type "hlfv1". Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system'

Answer (score 1):

Okay, answered my own question! My version of node had reverted to the non-LTS version. Issuing:

nvm use --lts

Got it working again.